# How to write FOR XML PATH and STUFF in join table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I tried to write a script in SQL Server to retrieve the data in the following structure from Table A and Table B

Output expected:

| event | method | channel_id | dest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Event A | GET | A123 | Dest 1 |
| Event A | GET | B123 | Dest 1 |
| Event C | POST | C123 | Dest 2:Dest 3 |

Table A

| id | event | method | routing_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Event A | GET | A1 |
| 2 | Event A | GET | B2 |
| 3 | Event C | POST | C3 |
| 4 | Event C | POST | C3 |

Table B

| id | channel_id | dest | routing_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A123 | Dest 1 | A1 |
| 2 | B123 | Dest 1 | B2 |
| 3 | C123 | Dest 2 | C3 |
| 4 | C123 | Dest 3 | C3 |

but for some reason, this always returns me the data set in the following format:

| event | method | channel_id | dest |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Event A | GET | A123 | Dest 1 |
| Event A | GET | B123 | Dest 1 |
| Event C | POST | C123 | Dest 2:Dest 3 |
| Event C | POST | C123 | Dest 2:Dest 3 |

Does anyone know what is going wrong with my script and how could I fix this issue? Thanks

This is my SQL script:

```
SELECT 
    mvr.event, mvr.method, oc.channel_id, 
    STUFF((SELECT '| ' + oc1.dest 
           FROM Table B oc1 
           WHERE oc1.routing_id = mvr.routing_id 
             AND oc1.channel_id = oc.channel_id
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS dest_name 
FROM 
    Table A mvr 
LEFT JOIN 
    Table B oc ON mvr.routing_id = oc.routing_id
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using `select @@version` Looks like you need `GROUP BY mvr.event, mvr.method, oc.channel_id`

Comment: Most supported versions of SQL Server support `STRING_AGG`, which clearly shows what you're trying to do rather than abusing `FOR XML` to perform string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not within the STUFF function, but because of your left join, multiplying your result set.
One row for every match "A.routing_id" = "B.routing_id"

I think the easiest solution would be to add a "DISTINCT" to your select, to remove the duplicate entries.
(This would work at least for your supplied sample data).

```
DECLARE @A TABLE(id int, event nvarchar(255), method nvarchar(255), routing_id nvarchar(255))
INSERT INTO @A(id, event, method, routing_id)
VALUES
(1, 'Event A', 'GET', 'A1')
,(2, 'Event A', 'GET', 'B2')
,(3, 'Event C', 'POST', 'C3')
,(4, 'Event C', 'POST', 'C3')

DECLARE @B TABLE(id int, channel_id nvarchar(255), dest nvarchar(255), routing_id nvarchar(255))
INSERT INTO @B(id, channel_id, dest, routing_id)
VALUES
(1, 'A123', 'Dest 1', 'A1')
,(2, 'B123', 'Dest 1', 'B2')
,(3, 'C123', 'Dest 2', 'C3')
,(4, 'C123', 'Dest 3', 'C3')


SELECT DISTINCT
    mvr.event, mvr.method, oc.channel_id,
    STUFF((SELECT '| ' + oc1.dest 
           FROM @B oc1 
           WHERE oc1.routing_id = mvr.routing_id 
             AND oc1.channel_id = oc.channel_id
           FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS dest_name 
FROM 
    @A mvr 
LEFT JOIN 
    @B oc ON mvr.routing_id = oc.routing_id
```